# Does a Druid in Wild Shape need hands to grapple?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, druid, grapple

The rules for grappling say "using at least one free hand", but there are plenty of examples of creatures that grapple without hands--Giant Toad and Octopus, Giant Constrictor Snake, etc., and many of those do it automatically on a successful hit. So what about other creature types? A bear? A giant viper? A shark? Or is this a matter of DM judgment call?

Answer (score 16):

**No. A druid in wild shape does not need hands to grapple, but the creature must have special rules regarding grapple if it does not have hands.**

The stat block of a creature trumps over the general rule of "requires hand" of grappling.

So If the creature has in its stat block the grapple ability, then it can grapple using the actions therein described. A druid in wild shape can grapple using the rules for the creature entry, not the rules for characters. The circumstances of the grapple are defined in the creature entry.

A creature that **does not meet at least one of:**

1. Have hands
2. Has a specific entry on how to treat grappling attempts.

Cannot grapple. A druid in wild shape cannot grapple if the creature fails the tests above.

Even if the druid can grapple, it can only do so within the means given by his shape. A giant squid grapples as a giant squid does (the rules in that stat block and the MM), not as a human (the rules in the PHB).

Example of a creature that does not have grapple rules, is available for wild shape but can grapple: [Ape](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Ape) - Apes have hands.

Comment: @NautArch they either use the creature block or the character one, depending on the circumstance. It is not interchangeable. A giant squid grapples as a giant squid, not as a human.

Comment: Are there any creatures that both have hands and have creature-block grappling rules and that could therefore do both?

Comment: Worth noting that some magical items permit grappling without hands (one of the tattoos in UA, for example) and that some of those might be available to at leas some forms that do not have hands and do not have grapple rules.

Comment: To be consistent a DM would need to also disallow grappling by all handless creatures without special grapple abilities, not just the druid wild shape. A wyvern then cannot carry off the unconscious warrior and the worg cannot drag the wizard into a cavern.